# Find boundaries to seperate peaks in a 3D plot using matlab or python

Tags: python, matlab

[image]

Could you tell me how to find boundaries to seperate the peaks in the 3D plot below?  Ideally, the boundaries are at local minimum. Peaks can be generated using Gaussian distributions with some noise.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any programming problem here, so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. You can probably get an answer about your data analysis problem on the [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), or perhaps [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you tried a watershed?